# Add class based on condition (for last rendered element with v-for)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm making a table in Vue.js and rendering some of the columns with the `v-for` directive:

```
<td v-for="(item, index) in items"> {{ item.name }} </td>
```

There is an unknown element count and I have to add a class to the last rendered element. I cannot use `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` because it is not the last `<td>` element in a row, it is just the last rendered element with `v-for` but there are also following `<td>` elements.

How could we achieve this in Vue.js?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `v-bind:class` directive.

```
<td v-for="(item, index) in items"
    v-bind:class="{ active: index==items.length-1 }"> {{ item.name }} </td>
```

CSS class:

```
.active {
   //some style
}
```

The solution is checking if `index` of an element is equal to `items.length-1`

```
v-bind:class="{ active: index==items.length-1 }"
```

**Working example**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items:[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item, index) in items"
          v-bind:class="{ active: index==items.length-1 }"> {{ item.name }} </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```